# Config.json property replacement in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have the following on an ASP.NET Core Startup:

```
builder
  .AddJsonFile("config.json", false)
  .AddJsonFile($"config.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true);
```

This way I can use the config files:

```
config.json
config.development.json
config.production.json
config.staging.json
```

If I have a property that is different in production but the same in development and staging should I place that property on config.json and other one in production to replace the valie in config.json?

Or do I need to add the property in config.development.json, config.production.json and config.staging.json and remove it from config.json?

I mean, is there property replacement in ASP.NET Core configs like there was in Web.config of ASP.NET 4?

Comment: if you have more than one configuration source and the property exists in more than one source, then the last source wins, so the order of adding configuration sources is important

Comment: In my case I always add config.json first and one of the other after, so that means that I have a property in config.json and another value only in config.production.json to replace the base one. This was what I wasn't sure ... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the source code that shows that config files are traversed in reverse order [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration/ConfigurationRoot.cs#L36)

`foreach (var provider in _providers.Reverse())`

Any key in `config.{hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json` would override same key in `config.json`